# How can I swapping link text to links and youtube link ot embed code YouTube in php

Tags: php, regex, youtube, swap

How can I swapping a text that has links and youtube url to embed youtube video:

```
$text = " normal text here 
            youtube : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx
            link : http://stackoverflow.com
            and some normal text here too.
            ";
```

Result :

```
youtube : <iframe width="529" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_URL_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
link : <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
some normal text here too.
```

Comment: _What?_ Could you explain perhaps what does your function do, what is your goal, what do you mean by "swap links"...?

Comment: I mean that I have something link post, and it has text and that text has normal text and links and youtube urls.
I want convert every links in text to href and every youtube urls embed code .
But that function after convert youtube url to embed code it will convert text links to hrefs so in the next step it will convert too inside **<iframe src="YOUTUBE_URL_HERE"></iframe>**  YOUTUBE_URL_HERE to href and that is problem .

Comment: I think it's better convert links in text with ignore **iframe tag**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function clickableLinksANDyoutubeIframe($text) {

    //swapping to embed youtube video
    $text = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i","<iframe width=\"529\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",$text);        

    //swapping to url href
    $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Zذضصثقفغعهخحجدشسيبلاتنمكطئءؤرلاىةوزظأإآ_]+)/', '<a href="/hashtag/$1" class="hashtaglink">#$1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)@([0-9a-zA-Zذضصثقفغعهخحجدشسيبلاتنمكطئءؤرلاىةوزظأإآ_-]+)/', '<a href="/$1" class="hashtaglink">@$1</a>', $text);
    $text = nl2br($text);

    //the result
    return $text;
```

}